# how to ignore all the node_modules folders from time machine

Tags: time-machine

How to add the node_modules folder paths to time machine ignore paths.
These folders are like tmp data for backups. These are very dense folders and also slow down TM.
Is there is a txt file which can be appended?
Maybe a command line which can append to the config.

Answer (score 27):

I'm one of the maintainers of [Asimov](https://github.com/stevegrunwell/asimov), a free macOS utility for automatically excluding development dependencies from Time Machine backups (npm, Composer, RubyGems, and more). It was designed for this very purpose ::looks begrudgingly at `node_modules/`::

The easiest way to install Asimov is via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (`brew install asimov`), but the GitHub repo also has manual installation instructions. Once installed, a cron job runs every day to find development dependencies and automatically exclude them from Time Machine via `tmutil` (mentioned above).

One more benefit is that Asimov checks for the dependency declarations (in the case of `node_modules/`, a `package.json` file) before excluding the directory from backups.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for building / sharing this utility. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW there is also https://github.com/tg44/heptapod available with a bit more "options".

Answer (score 4):

There're several approaches mentioned in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/peterdemartini/4c918635208943e7a042ff5ffa789fc1).

1. Using `tmutil addexclusion`

```
find `pwd` -type d -maxdepth 3 -name 'node_modules' | xargs -n 1 tmutil addexclusion
```

2. Using [`tmignore`](https://github.com/samuelmeuli/tmignore) which automatically finds all Git repositories on your disk and excludes all paths matching `.gitignore` files. I've just tried it and it works great. You can also set up a script to check your disk periodically.

Comment: Is there a tmutil command to show a list of excluded files/folders? I would like to confirm that the command has worked before actually running the backup.

Comment: @GeneParcellano I don't know about any. You could use `tmutil isexcluded [path]` to check specific path

Comment: Note that in more recent versions of macOS you might need to add the -p switch to tmutil. Also, you need to enable "Full Disk Access" privileges for *Terminal* otherwise the following appears when running tmutil:

tmutil: addexclusion requires Full Disk Access privileges.
To allow this operation, select Full Disk Access in the Privacy
tab of the Security & Privacy preference pane, and add Terminal
to the list of applications which are allowed Full Disk Access.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage the list of ignored folders in the Time Machine preferences.

[image]

Comment: this I know but its very hard to manage the GUI when a techie machine creates and destroys a dozen node project folders every day

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage *tmutil* Time Machine utility for managing such exclusions. Note that in more recent versions of macOS you might need to add the fixed path -p switch to tmutil as well as hold root privileges. Also, you need to enable "Full Disk Access" privileges for Terminal beforehand, otherwise the following appears when running tmutil separately:

> tmutil: addexclusion requires Full Disk Access privileges. To allow
> this operation, select Full Disk Access in the Privacy tab of the
> Security & Privacy preference pane, and add Terminal to the list of
> applications which are allowed Full Disk Access.

`find pwd -type d -maxdepth 3 -name 'node_modules' | xargs -n 1 sudo tmutil addexclusion -p`

PS. Because TM's config does not allow for regular expressions, you need to rerun this command whenever you create new project directories that needs similar exclusion.

Comment: I am getting `find: pwd: No such file or directory`

Comment: OP probably meant something like `find $(pwd)`